# CSSセレクター ”table > tbody > tr” が lxml で動きません

Tags: python, css, web-scraping

https://eiga.com/theater/13/
のサイトから、映画館の名前と住所を取得したいと思って、参考書を元にこのように書いてみました。

しかし以下のように表示され、住所が表示されません。

`{'url': 'https://eiga.com/theater/13/130301/3271/', 'name': ['アップリンク'], 'address': []}`

どのようにすればいいのかお手上げなので、ぜひアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？どうぞよろしくお願いします。

```python
import time
import re

import requests
import lxml.html

def main():
    session = requests.Session()
    response = requests.get('https://eiga.com/theater/13/')
    urls = scrape_list_page(response)
    for url in urls:
        time.sleep(1)
        response = session.get(url)
        theater = scrape_detail_page(response)
        print(theater)
        break

def scrape_list_page(response):
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)
    root.make_links_absolute(response.url)

    for a in root.cssselect('#pref_theaters a'):
        url = a.get('href')
        yield url

def scrape_detail_page(response):
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)
    theater = {
        'url': response.url,
        'name': [h2.text_content() for h2 in root.cssselect('#main > div.wrap_ctsBox > div > h2')],
        'address': [td.text_content() for td in root.cssselect('#ciBox > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td')],
    }
    return theater

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

使用しているCSSセレクタに `tbody` が含まれていますが、対象のHTMLコードでは `tbody` が省略されています。
`lxml` がパースするのは、このソースコードが対象ですので、`tbody` を削って、

```css
#ciBox > table > tr:nth-child(1) > td
```

とする必要があります。
ブラウザなどのDOMではタグが省略された要素が補われますから、上のセレクタはブラウザなどでは動かなくってしまいます。
例えば `table` と `tr` の間の `>` を削除すれば、どちらの環境でも動くセレクタになります。

```css
#ciBox > table tr:nth-child(1) > td
```